# how one smart contract interact with another smart contract using web3js?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3js

This is my doctor contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract doctor {

    struct doctor_ds {
        address doctor_address;
        string speciality;
    }
    mapping(address => doctor_ds) public doctors_list;
    address hospital_address;

    function doctor() {
        hospital_address = msg.sender;
    }

    function add_doctors(address _new_doctor_address, string _speciality) {

        doctors_list[_new_doctor_address].doctor_address = _new_doctor_address;
        doctors_list[_new_doctor_address].speciality = _speciality;
    }

    function doctor_exist(address _doctor) public view returns(bool) {
        if (doctors_list[_doctor].doctor_address == _doctor) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

================

This my patient contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./doctor.sol";

contract patient {

    doctor doctor_obj;

    function patient(address _doctor_contract) {
        doctor_obj = doctor(_doctor_contract);
    }

    function check_if_doctor(address _ddoctor) returns(bool) {

        return doctor_obj.doctor_exist(_ddoctor);
    }

    function add_doc(address _d, string _s) {
        doctor_obj.add_doctors(_d, _s);
    }

    function A() payable {

    }
}
```

I am getting gas exceeded error, when i am calling doctor exists in patient contract(using remix and private ethereum blockchain) and also i want to create front end  for patient contract, But How doctor contact's ABI will used in calling patient contract's add_doc and check_if_doctor functions. I  don't know code for  web3js when contracts interact with each other. Somebody please help

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to compile it after changing the patient constructor to:

```
doctor_obj = new doctor();
```

This way it will automatically create a new doctor contract when a patient is deployed. After that "add_doc" and "check_if_doctor" works just fine.

So, deploy the patient, the result abi will include both contracts functions because patient depends on doctor. I think you'll be able to use the same abi to interact directly with the two contracts. But the contract addresses will be different.

Comment: I have used interface in solidity and it works fine. Thanks siid for reply.